# import number variable from .ts to html <script>

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, import

I want to export the variable 'myVariable' from  **getVariable.ts**

```
export class getVariable {

      myVariable: number = 0;           

}
```

And use it in my html to show a button or not: I tried to import the .ts but there is no value in the variable 'myVariable'. How can I import the variable?

```
 <button type="button" id="btn1" class ="btn1"> btn1 </button>
 <button type="button" id="btn2" class="btn2"> btn2 </button>
 <script>          
                                import {getVariable } from "../getVariable ";
                                var statement = getVariable.myVariable;
                                if (statement != 0) {
                                    document.write('<button type="button" id="btn3" class="btn3"> btn3 </button>');
                                }
                                  
 </script>
```

Comment: It's a class but you haven't created an instance. You don't need a class anyway, use `const myVariables = { ... }`; and `export myVariables;`

Answer (score 0):

Prepend your variable with static.

```
export class getVariable {
 static myVariable: number = 0;           
}
```